# What is the keyword to get time in milliseconds in robot framework?

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

Currently I am getting time with the keyword `Get time epoch` , which is returning time in seconds. But I need time in milliseconds , So that I can get time span for a particular event.

or is there any other way to get the time span for a particular event or a testsceanrio?

Comment: What event are you wanting to measure? The time it takes for a keyword to run, or the time it takes for a testcase to run?

Comment: What "robot framework"?

Answer (score 4):

Check the new test library `DateTime`, which contains keyword `Get Current Date`, which also returns milliseconds. It also has keyword `Subtract Dates` to calculate difference between two timestamps.

Comment: How can I include DateTime test library in RIDE ??

Answer (score 4):

One of the more powerful features of robot is that you can directly call python code from a test script using the Evaluate keyword. For example, you can call the [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) function, and do a little math:

```
*** Test cases
| Example getting the time in milliseconds
| | ${ms}= | Evaluate | int(round(time.time() * 1000)) | time
| | log | time in ms: ${ms}
```

Note that even though `time.time` returns a floating point value, not all systems will return a value more precise than one second.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `DateTime library`, as suggested by [janne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23991689/586229):

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DateTime

*** Test Cases ***
Performance Test
    ${timeAvgMs} =    Test wall clock time    100    MyKeywordToPerformanceTest    and    optional    arguments
    Should be true    ${timeAvgMs} < 50

*** Keywords ***
MyKeywordToPerformanceTest
    # Do something here

Test wall clock time
    [Arguments]    ${iterations}    @{commandAndArgs}
    ${timeBefore} =    Get Current Date
    :FOR   ${it}    IN RANGE    ${iterations}
    \    @{commandAndArgs}
    ${timeAfter} =    Get Current Date
    ${timeTotalMs} =    Subtract Date From Date    ${timeAfter}    ${timeBefore}    result_format=number
    ${timeAvgMs} =    Evaluate    int(${timeTotalMs} / ${iterations} * 1000)
    Return from keyword    ${timeAvgMs}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the report, for each suite, test and keyword, you have the information about start, end and length with millisecond details. Something like:

```
Start / End / Elapsed:  20140602 10:57:15.948 / 20140602 10:57:16.985 / 00:00:01.037
```

Comment: Yeah , but How can I retrieve that time to Ride , I need to log that value in Ride ??

Comment: my answer is just to have the information afterwards, not to use it during the test/suite execution. I did not know exactly what you were trying to achieve. Erki's or Jane's answer should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do it using `Builtin`, look:

```
def get_time(format='timestamp', time_=None):
    """Return the given or current time in requested format.

    If time is not given, current time is used. How time is returned is
    is deternined based on the given 'format' string as follows. Note that all
    checks are case insensitive.

    - If 'format' contains word 'epoch' the time is returned in seconds after
      the unix epoch.
    - If 'format' contains any of the words 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour',
      'min' or 'sec' only selected parts are returned. The order of the returned
      parts is always the one in previous sentence and order of words in
      'format' is not significant. Parts are returned as zero padded strings
      (e.g. May -> '05').
    - Otherwise (and by default) the time is returned as a timestamp string in
      format '2006-02-24 15:08:31'
    """
    time_ = int(time_ or time.time())
    format = format.lower()
    # 1) Return time in seconds since epoc
    if 'epoch' in format:
        return time_
    timetuple = time.localtime(time_)
    parts = []
    for i, match in enumerate('year month day hour min sec'.split()):
        if match in format:
            parts.append('%.2d' % timetuple[i])
    # 2) Return time as timestamp
    if not parts:
        return format_time(timetuple, daysep='-')
    # Return requested parts of the time
    elif len(parts) == 1:
        return parts[0]
    else:
        return parts
```

You have to write your own module, you need something like:

```
import time

def get_time_in_millies():
    time_millies = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    return time_millies
```

Then import this library in Ride for the suite and you can use the method name like keyword, in my case it would be `Get Time In Millies`. More info [here](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/python/PythonTutorial.html).

Comment: Yeah , it works . I have added my own module .

Thx.